# Listing active *and past* network connections

Tags: linux, networking, lsof

On Linux, I know that I can list active network connections with `lsof -i` or netstat. However, as far as I know, this only list connections that are *currently open*.

If a process makes a short connection and then terminates it (like, for instance, a program "phoning home"), I would miss it unless I happen to run `lsof` in that exact moment. Is there a way to get a list of servers I have connected to? For instance, a tool that writes the IP address on a file whenever a new connection is opened, system-wide.

Keeping a network sniffer such as wireshark permanently open just for this task seems overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a process makes a short connection and then terminates it (like, for instance, a program "phoning home")

Most of these programs creates a TCP connection to guarantee the information will arrive to 'home'. If this is the case, then the `netstat` command will be your best friend, because all closed TCP connection keep for a small or a bit longer time at `TIME_WAIT` state, and `netstat --inet -n` lists these connections (and currently opened ones, too).

If you are not lucky and that sneaky process uses UDP connection or you want to monitor the traffic for a longer period, then you have to monitor the complete network traffic of the machine with tools like TCPDump or IPTraf. IPTraf is more simple, because it records only IP addresses and ports, TCPDump is a more advanced tool (despite its name, it can monitor UDP and ICMP traffic too) and it records all network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but have you considered using iptables with a `LOG` target on the output chain?

Something like the following (untested, but gets the gist across).

```
iptables -I OUTPUT ! -i lo -p tcp --syn -j LOG --log-prefix 'New TCP'
iptables -I OUTPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix 'New UDP'
```

This will log once for each TCP connection, and once for each new UDP session, excluding the loopback interface, which seems to be roughly what you are asking for. You can then `grep` your system logs to find out after the fact which outgoing connections have been made.

However, it won't (and I don't think plain iptables can) tell you which application initiated the connection, and you will get *tons* of logs from this which will likely mostly be of no use (because the number of legitimate connections made will certainly dwarf any phoning-home done).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, too. I don't know why it didn't cross my mind to use firewall-level logging. Thanks.

Comment: `# iptables -I OUTPUT ! -i lo -p tcp --syn -j LOG --log-prefix 'New TCP'
iptables v1.4.21: Can't use -i with OUTPUT

Try 'iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
`

Answer (score -1):

You need to listen more then 65000 ports. Only network sniffer of firewall can do it. Just configure correct filter (for new connection requests) for sniffer or firewall log rules.